# Laravel - Problema con un dd y una vista

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Sucede que estoy llamando una vista .blade de laravel

Primero el llamado de la ruta a controlador

```
Route::get('administrator', [
'as' => 'administrator',
'uses' => 'LogicBusiness\lb_userController@index']
);
```

Luego el llamado del controlador a la vita

```
public function index()
{
    return view('UsersAndSecurity.Users.index');
}
```

Y el contenido del archivo es este

```
<h1>Alejo Florez</h1>
```

Como ven, no existe ningún dd en este llamado sencillo del archivo.

Pero cuando voy al navegador para ver la vista aparece

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tiene alguna explicación por que laravel me esta mostrando esto dd si en ningún punto se esta llamando?

Por cierto, version de laravel es 5.1

Comment: Con la reputación que tienes, deberías tener claro que el código se agrega como texto y no como imagen.

Comment: Entiendo, ya corrijo

Comment: Sin duda alguna el dd() o dump() se está llamando en alguna parte. ¿Ya hiciste una búsqueda en todo tu código?

Comment: Si, fue mi primera acción, pero ni dd(), ni dump() aparecen en todo el código

Comment: Y el código de tu vista cual es, si no esta en el controller estará en la vista.

Comment: @EduardoJavierMaldonado antes de mostrar una vista, Laravel pasa por al menos 50 archivos distintos, así que puede estar en muchos lugares distintos, tal vez con fines de testing.